# Do beacons affect both myself and enemy units?

Tags: loop-hero

The description for a beacon says it offers "+20% attack speed for all units." Does this mean the attack speed buff applies to both myself and enemy units? Or does my own character not count as a unit?

[image: A]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes beacons affect both you and enemy units as well, we usually assume "all units" means everyone, unless specified. The boss is not affected by the beacon though.

Some links:

- [Steam community forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1282730/discussions/0/3112522283890341736/)
- [Steam community forum 2](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1282730/discussions/0/3112522283872700803/)

Comment: Sounds like the beacon puts you at a disadvantage since time passes at the same speed.